# Get Start and End Datetime of DFT for logging purpose

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016

In my ssis package there are quite a few DFTs. I need to log start and end date time of each DFT for logging purpose.

I could handle the End date time SQL command only but struggling on how to handle Start Datetime of the DFT. I know, i could gather the start date time of the package via expression in a variable but not sure how to do it in DFT.

I do not have sequence defined for the DFTs so i can not do it in control flow and need to do it inside DFT only.

Can some one please suggest an approach.

Comment: This is already in the SSIS logs

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Can you please guide me, may be some reference material or keywords i need to search for.

Comment: @Mohit are you running your package from visual studio or using dtexec utility or a .Net app or anything else?

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/10/17/querying-the-ssis-catalog-here-s-a-handy-query.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Event Handlers" below tasks have been added, will usually be grey until you add a task

[image]

This will execute before anything else for that task executes. Or according to the dropdown, after, onError etc.

You can then run a GETDATE there save it to a variable, or write the audit entry directly. basically do anything you would/could have in a dataflow and out.

Answer (score 1):

This information are already found in your ssis log.

1. If you are running your package from visual studio you have to go to `Progress / Execution Results` Tab (It will appear after executing the package.

[image]

2. If you are running your package using DTExec utility you can use the following command to save the package log to a text file:

   ```
   dtexec /f "c:\pkgOne.dtsx" /l "DTS.LogProviderTextFile;c:\log.txt"
   ```
3. If you are using a .Net application read this [Enable Logging programatically MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136023.aspx)

**References**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a67e4a3a-0580-4a13-86a6-25476a17c598/saving-ssis-results-to-log-or-text-file-using-dtexec?forum=sqlintegrationservices